# How to delete postgresql databases matching a pattern?

Tags: database, postgresql, pattern-matching

With pgAdmin III, I can list all the databases on my postgresql server.

But with pgAdmin, I can delete only 1 database at the time. It takes a lot of time to delete, for example, 30 databases, one by one...

So, what would be your approach to delete, for example, all the databases with a name containing the word "june"?

Probably I will have to build a Bash script. No problem with this. But which command would you use in this script?

I have search the web for many hours without success for this problem...

Thanks to help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
psql -c "copy (select datname from pg_database where datname like '%june%') to stdout" | while read line; do
    echo "$line"
    #dropdb -i "$line"
done
```

Or using `for` loop which is more reliable (`while` block executed in the parent context so it is necessary to do some additional movements for its body):

```
for dbname in $(psql -c "copy (select datname from pg_database where datname like '%june%') to stdout") ; do
    echo "$dbname"
    #dropdb -i "$dbname"
done
```

Also option `-X` for `psql` (do not use `~/.psqlrc` file) could be good to avoid unnecessary outputs.

For `psql` and `dropdb` utilities you probably need to provide the connection options ([see documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/reference-client.html))

Comment: Works on psql 12 without confirmation: `for dbname in $(psql -c "copy (select datname from pg_database where datname like 'test%') to stdout"); do echo "$dbname"; dropdb "$dbname"; done;`

Answer (score 2):

Lots of good, robust solutions; but here is a bash one-liner to keep in the ol' grimoire:

```bash
psql -Atqc "SELECT 'DROP DATABASE ' || quote_ident(datname) || ';' FROM pg_database WHERE datname like '%june%';" | psql
```

This uses a `SELECT` statement that builds some strings around the `datname`s returned by a query against the `pg_database` table.

```
SELECT 'DROP DATABASE ' || quote_ident(datname) || ';' 
FROM pg_database WHERE datname like '%june%';
```

This is executed directly from the shell using arguments to `psql` to:

> `-A`     Turn off fill justification when printing out table
> elements.

> `-t`     Turn off printing of column names  and  result  row
> count.   This is useful with the -c option in shell
> scripts.

> `-q` Specifies that psql should do its work quietly.  By
> default,  it  prints  welcome and exit messages and
> prompts for each query.  If this  option  is  used,
> none  of  this  happens. This is useful with the -c
> option.

> `-c query` Specifies that psql is to execute one query string,
> query,  and  then  exit.  This  is useful for shell
> scripts,  typically  in  conjunction  with  the  -q
> option in shell scripts

All of this is then piped into another invocation of `psql` with `| psql` when then executes the `DROP DATABASE` queries

Answer (score 1):

Big thanks to [Abelisto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38625070/1098603).

Here are our last script that works well, after many months of search.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
export PGPASSWORD="xxxxx"

PATTERN=$1

echo "Pattern parameter: $PATTERN"

/usr/bin/psql -U odoo -d postgres -c "copy (select datname from pg_database where datname like '%$PATTERN%') to stdout" | while read line; do
    echo "$line"
    dropdb -U xxxx "$line"
done
echo
echo "Databases which names matches pattern $PATTERN were deleted!"
echo
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a more elegant way is to use a for loop.

Note that options `-t` and `-A` makes psql return only data (no headers nor extra whitespace). This allows you to directly create a bash array from psql.

```sh
# drop all molnet* databases
sql="select datname from pg_database where datname like '%june%'"
dbDelNames=`psql -U postgres -t -A -c "$sql"`
for dbName in ${dbDelNames[@]}
do
    echo -e "\n\n[INFO] Drop $dbName.\n"
    psql -U postgres -c "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ${dbName};"
done
```